# How to instantiate a struct in python cffi?

Tags: python, python-cffi, cffi

I'm trying to instantiate a struct using the Python cffi library.  I'd like to instantiate a struct from my own .h file as well as ones from the standard library.

```
import datetime
import os
from cffi import FFI

clib = None

script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

ffi = FFI()
with open(os.path.join(script_path, 'myheader.h'), 'r') as myfile:
    source = myfile.read()
    ffi.cdef(source)
clib = ffi.dlopen('mylib')

# these all fail
ffi.new("struct tm")
ffi.new("struct tm[]", 1)
ffi.new("struct tm *")
ffi.new("struct mystruct")
```

Comment: The contents of myheader.h (at minimum the definition of struct "tm" and/or "mystruct") would be very helpful. Also, the error is missing. It's probably something like "ffi.error: undefined struct/union name" but if it's something else, then there's something else at play.

Answer (score 2):

`ffi.new("struct mystruct")` is incorrect, you probably mean `ffi.new("struct mystruct *")`.

`struct tm` is most probably not defined in the `cdef()`, i.e. in your case, it is not mentioned inside `myheader.h`.  You need to define it in the `cdef()` before you can use it, even if it is in one of the common standard headers.

You're probably better off using `set_source()` for that (the API mode), because you can then use an approximate definition of `struct tm`, e.g. something like:

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;
    int tm_min;
    int tm_hour;
    int tm_mday;
    int tm_mon;
    int tm_year;
    ...;       /* literally a "..." here */
};
```

If you use `dlopen()` (the ABI mode), then you must instead use exactly the same declaration as found in your platform's headers.  The result is less portable.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Armin is probably right (and is definitely the expert here). If `tm` is the struct from ctime, you need to define it. If it's your own struct, but it's not defined in `myheader.h` you need to add the definition or read in the pertinent header to your `source` string. If all else fails, you may need to `typedef` it.

This won't work:

```
ffi.new("struct tm")
```

This should work:

```
ffi.new("struct tm[]", 1)
```

But this one looks better:

```
ffi.new("struct tm *")
```

However, this one doesn't make sense to me:

```
ffi.new("struct mystruct")
```

If `tm` is being defined as a typedef, then you don't need `struct`. If you redefined ctime tm as mystruct, you need a "*" here. If it is a typedef, you can't specify struct, but this would work instead:

```
ffi.new("mystruct *")
```

I've not been able to get structs to work that aren't a `typedef`. If Armin hadn't implied otherwise, I'd have declared they aren't supported. Maybe you've hit the same problem.

If you have any control or say over your header files and struct names, I highly recommend typedef'ing your structs, anyway. This is a general practice for structs in C.

```
typedef struct tm {
/* struct internals here */
} tm; // not recommended using this short of a name though
```

Unless `tm` is **completely** core to your code, so much that it's meaning is always obvious, a more descriptive name is highly recommended when using typedef. This becomes a global definition, so it also helps avoid any collisions, e.g. with the `ctime` struct `tm`. This would be better:

```
typedef struct {
/* struct internals here */
} taskmaster; // or something similarly descriptive, having nothing else to go on I assume 'tm' is referring to my favorite UK panel show and not ctime
```

You can also drop `tm` entirely as I did here. Only the final type name is required when using typedef.

Anyway, the point is with `typedef` you **don't** use `struct` in your declaration:

```
mytm = ffi.new("tm *") # again, this level of abbreviation is not recommended
```

or

```
mytm = ffi.new("taskmaster *")
```

Also remember CFFI doesn't understand directives, like #include. So if `myheader.h` doesn't define `struct tm` but pulls it from another file (such as ctime), you either need to define it specially or (read and) add all the header files of interest to your `source` string for the cdef call. Reading in standard lib headers is *not* suggested.